# Fixing the  IE 12030 repeatability bug for Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I just loop my Ajax call until the 12030 error goes away.  The error is reported as a bug [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_23421667.html)

Does anyone know if there is a better fix...as this takes up time to loop. I read this was a known issue with IE that it intermittently produces 12030 errors as that Ajax status.

```
var Ajax = {
    createAjaxObject: function()
    {
        var request;
        try
        {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            try 
            {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                try
                {
                    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(error)
                {
                    request = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return request;
    },

    useAjaxObject: function( path, param, ajax_func, html_div )
    {
        var object = new Ajax.createAjaxObject();
        object.open( "POST", path, true );
        object.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        object.setRequestHeader( "Content-length", param.length );
        object.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );
        object.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if( this.readyState === 4 )
            {
                if( this.status === 200 )
                {
                    ajax_func( this.responseText, html_div );
                }
                else
                {
                    Ajax.repeatUseAjaxObject( path, param, ajax_func, html_div );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
        object.send( param );
        return true;
    },
    repeatUseAjaxObject: function( path, param, ajax_func, html_div )
    {
        var state = false,
            count = 1;
        while(state === false && count <= 5)
        {
            state = Ajax.useAjaxObject( path, param, ajax_func, html_div );
            if( count !== 1 )
            {
                alert( 'Ajax Object Use Failed ');
            }
        count++;
        }
        return state;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more details? Like the version of IE and what code you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this same problem, and I found a solution that works for me as long as the AJAX request is asynchronous.

The solution is to wrap the AJAX call in a `setTimeout` call with a delay of 0.

This seems to work 100% of the time for me.

I also verified with one of my co-workers that the 12030 error still occurs in Internet Explorer 9, as well.

`<rant>So Billy G and company see fit to provide us with the new "Metro" interface, but they can't be bothered to fix their browser that all web programmers must support</rant>`

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented bug with the underlying socket handling of XMLHttpRequest in internet explorer.

When you use the XMLHttpRequest object to read a response from the server, the server must have cleared the read buffer first. (even if its not interested in it).

Ensure your server side code reads the entire request bytes before sending the response.

If you specify what server technology you're using I might be able to give you an example.

Comment: I'm using Linux Apache MysQL PHP.

Comment: I don't think this is a server issue.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are looping, but perhaps setting a timeout for your retry rather than looping would be a good way to avoid the user perceiving the delay (unless you really do mean to prevent other JavaScript from executing until you get the answer!) This doesn't prevent the error, but it would be a client-side only way of mitigating the impact on the browser. (I'm assuming from your comment "as this takes up time to loop" that the browser lag. is your real problem).

Actually, I'm possibly taking you too literally... Now that I think about it an actual loop would prohibit subsequent requests too. Can you be more specific about your "looping" technique? and what you mean by "takes up time"?

Comment: Here is my loop it is just 5 repetitive calls...I have not been on IE for while so I haven't actually seen the alert pop up.

Comment: It's not the lag..it's that I don't know why this is happening and I don't want to get in the habit of looping repeatability issues.